# Move win7 to another machine: working machine on every step

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup

I want window7 ("C" and "D") move to another machine with all installed programs.

As I understand the sequnce of step is following:

1. sysprep /generalize
2. reboot with mini windows and use
   imagex to copy partitions.
3. Boot machine 2 with mini windows and use imagex to fill hard drives

All good, but on every step I want have at least one working machine, and it is unclear for me, what happening with machine one after step 1.

I read

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721973(WS.10).aspx

but not understand, not default users will be removed? What about programs and register? So what exactly, I lost after step 1 on machine one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made experiment, and answer is yes and no.

On the first site after `imagex /capture | imagex /apply`
your machine one become unusable, after "step 1" and reboot, it tells "Partly fixed, please reboot" and
this infinite cycle. And machine two shows the same picture. And you can not repair
this using windows installation disk without full uninstall and install fresh copy of windows.

But I finally found solution: "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\msoobe.exe", so yes it (machine one after sysprep /generalize) become unusable, but this is possible to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Machine one should continue to work at every step.

As for what is 'lost', from [Sysprep Command-Line Syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721973%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for /generalize:

> The security ID (SID) resets, any system restore points
>   are cleared, and event logs are deleted.
>
> The next time the computer starts, the specialize configuration pass
>   runs. A new security ID (SID) is created, and the clock for Windows
>   activation resets, if the clock has not already been reset three
>   times.